Weird error in RegionPlot3D?
I am trying to plot a sphere with radius varying with the angles.
Here is the code
r[\[Phi]_, \[Theta]_] = 
  2 (1 + SphericalHarmonicY[1, 1, \[Theta], \[Phi]] - 
     SphericalHarmonicY[1, -1, \[Theta], \[Phi]] + 
     2 SphericalHarmonicY[1, 0, \[Theta], \[Phi]]);
reg = ImplicitRegion[
   x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 
    r[ToSphericalCoordinates[{x, y, z}][[3]], 
      ToSphericalCoordinates[{x, y, z}][[2]]]^2, {x, y, z}];
ParametricPlot3D[{r[\[Phi], \[Theta]] Cos[\[Phi]] Sin[\[Theta]], 
  r[\[Phi], \[Theta]] Sin[\[Phi]] Sin[\[Theta]], 
  r[\[Phi], \[Theta]] Cos[\[Theta]]}, {\[Theta], 0, Pi}, {\[Phi], 0, 
  2 Pi}]
RegionPlot3D[reg, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, {z, -4, 4}]

The first line defines the radius function, the second line defines the region as being inside the deformed ball. (Can I use spherical coordinates directly? I.e. define implicit region by "radius<r(phi,theta)"?)
The parametric plot gives the boundary. Output of RegionPlot3D
(*RegionPlot3D::boolf: ImplicitRegion[...] must be a Boolean function*)
For constant $r$, this works however.

Please read the documentation for RegionPlot3D. The first argument should be a predicate, not a region. So RegionPlot3D[First@reg, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, {z, -4, 4}].

Oops, you are right. I think I copied that code from this site, where the radius was constant and it worked. This is why I got confused. Any Idea why Volume does not work for this  reg?

Or RegionPlot3D[RegionMember[reg, {x, y, z}], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, {z, -4, 4}]


RegionPlot3D support the form RegionPlot3D[reg] where reg is ImplicitRegion.

Since RegionPlot3D need to Discrete the region, we set PlotRange for some cases.


RegionPlot3D[reg, PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}, 
 PlotPoints -> 80]



We can test another settings for RegionPlot3D the ImplicitRegion.

RegionPlot3D[ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1, {x, y, z}], 
   PlotPoints -> 30, 
   Method -> {"DiscretizationMethod" -> #}] & /@ {Automatic, 
  "Symbolic"}


